# gets record of customers who not commenting about goods

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables customers and cust_comment.

customers table contains:

```
cust_id,
f_name,
l_name
```

and cust_comment contains

```
cust_id,
comm_id,
txt_comment
```

some of customers commenting about good and some of them doesn't commenting

I want to show in customers profile:  *"you still have not comment"*

Thanks all

Comment: So, What have you tried?

Comment: @unforgiven new answer posted .Check it .

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT customer.cust_id as `customer_id` , customer.*,(select    
count(comm_id) from cust_comment where cust_id = `customer_id`) as   
comment_count 
FROM `customer` having comment_count =0
```

You will get desired result .

Comment: Bikash thanks, your code work good. You're a decent rating. but i want to show message of  "you still have not comment" in customers profile separately.so i should use where cust_id=$custid . where use this phrase ?

Comment: just before having clause like FROM `customer` where cust_id=$custid having comment_count =0

Comment: And one more thing .If answer is helpful please mark as helpful.So that it can be helpful to others also .Thanks